# Populate preceding value using case statement in Hive

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hiveql, hive-query

I have a column `event` in `Hive` table like below.

```
Event

Sent
Sent
Open
Open
Click
Sent
Open
Signup
Sent
Open
Click
```

Now I want to create new column based on the values in `event` column using case statement.

I want to where there is `signup` in event column I want the `Previous_event` column to be exactly the `preceding` value.

I have tried like below.

```
select event, 
       case when event = 'Sent' then 'No_event' 
            when event = 'Open' then 'Sent' 
            when event = 'Click' then 'Open'  
            else -1 
       end as Previous_event 
from table;
```

`Result`

```
Sent    No_event
Sent    No_event
Open    Sent
Open    Sent
Click   Open
Sent    No_event
Open    Sent
Signup  -1
Sent    No_event
Open    Sent
Click   Open
```

`Expected result`

```
Sent    No_event
Sent    No_event
Open    Sent
Open    Sent
Click   Open
Sent    No_event
Open    Sent
Signup  Open
Sent    No_event
Open    Sent
Click   Open
```

How can i achieve what I want?

Comment: Do you have a PK (some id field) in this table, which determines the order of these rows. SQL in general is an un-ordered dataset. So, without any `id` defined, we cannot identify what comes first and what comes later !

Comment: You can't be using MySQL and Hive, which is it?

Comment: Also, the comment about a primary key: you actually just need a column to explicitly order the data by. Potentially a timestamp column?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya There is no primary key in this table

Comment: @MatBailie I wanted to see if `mysql` code can work with `hive` as most of them work

Comment: @nmr any timestamp/datetime based field, which can be used to determine which event (row) "logically" comes first ?

Comment: MySQL and Hive have different Syntax for all sorts of things.  If you're targeting this at Hive, say you want an answer for Hive.  A MySQL answer in ***not*** guaranteed to run on Hive, and Hive has functionality that MySQL doesn't have *(except in MySQL 8...)*

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya `eventdate` I order the records by serialnumber and eventdate

Comment: @nmr check the answer - see if it works ? It is specifically for MySQL

Comment: If Hive version 0.11 or above, can use the LEAD and LAG function
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the URLs that contain similar Problem/Solution:

[Hive access previous row value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34101365/hive-access-previous-row-value)

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/39533/fill-null-with-previous-row-values-in-hive.html

The SQL will be :

```
select event, prev_event(event) as Previous_event from table;
```

The code for the UDF :

```
    import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;

    public class cum_mul extends UDF  {
    private String prevValue = null;

    public String evaluate(String value) {

    switch(value) 
        { 
            case "Sent": 
        prevValue = "No_event";
                return "No_event"; 
            case "Open": 
        prevValue = "Sent";
                return "Sent";  
            case "Click": 
        prevValue = "Open";
                return "Open"; 
            default: 
                return prevValue; 
        } 
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a correlated subquery.

Based on [OP's comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52504910/populate-preceding-value-using-case-statement-in-hive?noredirect=1#comment91951036_52504910), you can try the following query (**for MySQL**):

```
select t1.event, 
       case when t1.event = 'Sent' then 'No_event' 
            when t1.event = 'Open' then 'Sent' 
            when t1.event = 'Click' then 'Open' 
            when t1.event = 'Signup' then (select t2.event 
                                           from table as t2 
                                           where t2.eventdate < t1.eventdate 
                                           order by t2.eventdate desc 
                                           limit 1)         
            else -1 
       end as Previous_event 
from table as t1;
```

Comment: This is giving me `Unsupported SubQuery Expression  Currently SubQuery expressions are only allowed as Where and Having Clause predicates` in hive Is there a different way to do this

Comment: @nmr not sure about hive. Since your question was tagged both MySQL and Hive, I gave a MySQL specific solution